# How to put javascript code in another javascript code

Tags: javascript

I would like to put

```
<div id='gallerysharebar'>
    <div id='fbshare' class='fb-like' data-href='http://www.facebook.com' data-send='false' data-layout='button_count' data-width='100' data-show-faces='false' data-font='tahoma'>
    </div>
    <a id='pinterest-icon' href='
javascript:void((function(){var e=document.createElement('script');e.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');e.setAttribute('charset','UTF-8');e.setAttribute('src','http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r='+Math.random()*99999999);document.body.appendChild(e)})());
'><img onclick='doPinIt();' src='/wp-content/themes/bliss/images/pin-it.png' alt='Pin It'/></a>
</div>
```

this code in xxx part of the javascript code. The problem is that code is all javascript so  when I put the above code directly it crashes the gallery.

```
   f.fn.tn3.version = "1.1.0.44";
    f.fn.tn3.config = {
        data: null,
        skin: null,
        skinDir: "skins",
        skinDefault: '..........<div class="tn3-show-albums"></div><div class="tn3-next-page"></div><div class="tn3-prev-page"></div>**xxxxxxxx**<div class="tn3-play"></div>...........',
        cssID: null
    };
```

Comment: please format the code and separate the html from the javascript.

Comment: so, you tried to put the html on top into the skinDefault property below, where the xxx's are? And what happened? your facebook and pinterest-icons don't show up?

Comment: no because pinterest has javascript code in it and skinDefault property is also javscript so when I put that code into skinDefault it becomes javascript in javascript. I know from php I need to pause brackets and put php code in this kind of cases but I don't know about javascript. I can also pay for this change if anybody could make it Im tired of it!

Comment: no you don't need to do any goofy brackets like you would in php. The javascript inside of the pinterest stuff can just be thought of as html. Forget it even exists. When you click one of those things, it will execute and all will be well. All you need to worry about is getting it on the page. That being said... Can you describe what you see? Is the stuff inside `skinDefault` showing up at all, before or after you try to add the gallerysharebar stuff?

Comment: btw if you don't want to deal with this stuff, you might be better off cutting your losses and using something like [addthis](http://www.addthis.com) for your social links.

Comment: I know. addthis doesn't support pinterest. My goal is to add pinterest and facebook into my tn3 gallery. tn3 gallery is working with this huge javascript file. and skinDefault has all divs that are on the page in it. Everything from arrows to fullscreen. If i can place a div in it with facebook and pinterest in it I can position it with css and then it would work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get it now. There is a problem with your quotes (`'` vs. `"`). You are using single quotes in your skinDefault string, so as soon as you paste in the above html, it ends the string and you get a parse error from the stuff after the first single quote. So, to fix this, replace all single quotes in the html with double quotes. Please let me know if that works and if not, what errors you see.

**EDIT:**
I am pretty sure the quotes inside the attributes won't work and you will need to replace them with `&quot;`. Either way, try it as is first and then let me know if you think you need the `&quot;` and I'll update my answer.

```
<div id="gallerysharebar">
    <div id="fbshare" class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false" data-font="tahoma">
    </div>
    <a id="pinterest-icon" href="javascript:void((function(){var e=document.createElement("script");e.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");e.setAttribute(\"charset\",\"UTF-8");e.setAttribute("src","http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r="+Math.random()*99999999);document.body.appendChild(e)})());">
        <img onclick="doPinIt();" src="/wp-content/themes/bliss/images/pin-it.png" alt="Pin It"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you ! It's worked just fine but I also need to put image link into facebook like button so when you click you can like it. Anyways I gave up. I'm gonna do it by position:absolute;bottom:50px; from footer.

Comment: @user627850 You're welcome! now you just gotta make friends with a web developer so you don't have to keep banging your head with this stuff ;)

Comment: true.. my name is ... nice to meet you lbstr =) lets start now :) ahah